# Add uniform spacing between objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rectangles, spacing

Given a set of rectangles, how do you add a specified amount of space between them while also preserving the size of each rectangle?

[image: objects touching]
Original

[image: objects spaced]
Spaced

The above example simply reduces the size of each rectangle.  This is not possible in the actual implementation because the rectangles need to maintain their original sizes.

I have thought about using the above approach and then scaling up the parent.  If this is the suggested method, how do you get the value to scale by to maintain the original sizes and keep the spacing to an exact value?

In a standard grid you can use an iterative approach `position += i * spacing`, however the number of columns or rows preceding any given rectangle is not necessarily known or easily calculated (maybe there is good way to calculate this?).  I have only been able to think of brute force algorithms and would like to avoid that if at all possible.

The rectangles are contained within a `List<Rect>`.
All rectangles are touching with no gaps and form a larger rectangle.

I am sure there are known algorithms for this, but I have been unable to find any reference material.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Just throwing this out there, as I find the question interesting. If you try the approach that requires you to _"scaling up the parent"_, can you get the scale % you need for the form based on the difference of the rectangle size between the Original and Spaced versions?

Comment: @quaabaam It seems likely that is the best approach.  Originally it seemed like the math would get complex, but thinking about it now it should be straightforward.  I will start testing and check in with an update.  Thanks.

Comment: After testing this approach, it is clear this is not the correct direction to take.   The original thought was to subtract the spacing from both axes, then scale everything back up.  Unfortunately this changes the aspect of the rectangles (as shown in my example image above).  Will be trying some other approaches.